# How to inspect React Native element with component name?

Tags: react-native, react-devtools, react-native-debugger

I'm looking for how to inspect elements with component names.
As you know, when we use react devtools, it only shows us the unfamiliar iOS component name.
I googled a lot about this, but I couldn't find about it so far.
Can anyone please let me know if you have an idea of how to inspect React Native elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**there are two ways:**

**1-you can check the component name by inspecting it in react native by command + D (⌘D) then  select show inspector.**

**2- you can use React Developer Tools. Check the following link https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#react-developer-tools.**

images :
1- by **inspecting** [image]

2- by **react dev tools** [image]

3- by **react dev tools** [image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know, but sometimes the inspector doesn't show the box which is showing margin, padding and others

Comment: I think you need to reload your inspect or app by dev tools